# Why the installation of firebase tools not working: "npm install -g firebase-tools" , I have already installed node js and setup firebase console

Tags: node.js, windows, firebase, npm-install, firebase-tools

[Here it appears whenever I give command "npm install -g firebase-tools"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9sLv.png),
I have already installed node.js and set up firebase console

I have tried many ways to solve the problem, but I am not getting the correct solution

Comment: Did you restart your terminal after installing Node.js?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.